# Regarding periodic functions and their domain of definition

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have a periodic function $f$ defined on R. I want to show that any periodic and continuous function attains its maximum and minimum on R. I suspect that it suffices to consider a compact subset $C = [x,x+p]$, s.t: $p>0$ is the period of $f$. My justification for this is that $f(x+p) = f(x)$ $\forall x \in R$, however, I am having trouble formalizing this. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Be more precise: where do you find troubles? The way you are proceeding is the right one!

Comment: Start by proving a bound on $C$ is a bound everywhere: if $M$ is such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert\leq M$ for any $x\in[0,p]$, then  $\lvert f(x) \rvert\leq M$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (e.g., by contradiction.) So the $\sup$ (and similarly the $\inf$) will be the same on $C$ and on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ and $m$ be the maximum and the minimum of $f$ on $[0,p]$. Let $x\in\mathbb R$. Then there are $u\in [0,p]$ and $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $x = u + kp$. Hence, $f(x) = \ldots\,\le\,M$ and $f(x) = \ldots\,\ge\,m$.

Comment: Can I just say: $u = x + kp$ since $k \in Z$ $\implies$ $f(u) = f(x + kp) \leq M$ $\implies$ $f(x + p(k+1)) \leq M, \forall x \in R$. Thus, if $|f(x)| \leq M, \forall x \in [0,p]$ $\implies$ $|f(x)| \leq M, \forall x \in R$?

Comment: I do not understand what you write here. You have $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in [0,p]$. So, if $x\in\mathbb R$, $x = u + kp$, with $u\in [0,p]$ and $k\in\mathbb Z$, then $f(x) = f(u + kp) = f(u)\le M$ since $u\in [0,p]$. Now, do the same with the minimum.

Comment: It was supposed to be the absolute value of $f$, sorry if that was unclear. So my argument that $f(x) \leq M$ $\forall x \in R$ was correct? That is what was I was trying to ask.

Comment: No, it wasn't. If absolute value or not - I don't get what you did there.

Comment: If you take $u \in [0,p]$ and $x \in R$, does that not make what I did clear? It seems almost identical to what you wrote.

Comment: I don't see this $(k+1)$ thing in my argument...

Comment: Ahh.. There I was trying to use the fact that $f(x) = f(x+p)$

Comment: You even have $f(x) = f(x + kp)$ for every $k\in\mathbb Z$ (proved by induction from $f(x) = f(x+p)$). That's what I used in my argument.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks so much!